# Building for 'xrOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/visionOS2/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a[5](MeshSkinningNEON64_blzfc.o)) built for 'xrOS'

Tags: unity-game-engine, visionos

i'm simply trying to create a test build with Unity to visionOS simulator. Using 2022.3.5f1 LTS.

Having this problem in XCode 15.0 beta 4.

Any ideas? Thanks!

#visionOS

Rebuild a new project, added xrOS in excluded Architectures